# Fetch images of instagram users without redirects

Tags: instagram-api

I want to allow my SPA's user to authenticate with his Instagram account in place, i.e. show the login form & authenticate on the very same page with the ultimate goal of showing him his photos.

I know this is not the way to authenticate with Instagram. I am driven though by a variety of reasons:

- Facebook client SDK allows me to do that already, hence I need consistency.
- My application's state is not managed by any state management library so redirecting back to the initial page and resuming the state of things will be a little cumbersome.
- For the sake of UX.

I would like to hear your input on the matter and if you can come up with any proposal of producing the desired behavior.

I have thought of doing everything in an IFrame which I would manipulate as a login prompt but again the response comes with an `X-Frame-Options : sameorigin`.

Answer (score 0):

The case was answered by utilizing a window popup.

[Proposed solution](https://www.codexworld.com/login-with-instagram-using-javascript-sdk/)